# How to filter n consecutive days from a start date in a vector of dates across multiple years in R?

Tags: r

I'm stucked trying to create a code that filters 5 consecutive days from a vector of dates starting from a given start date, across multiple years.

Example:

```
v = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), 1)

initial_date = as.Date("01-01") #(mm:dd)
```

Expected output:

```
2000-01-01 #(YYYY:mm:dd)
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04
2000-01-05
2001-01-01
2001-01-02
2001-01-03
2001-01-04
2001-01-05
...
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
2020-01-05
```

If the initial date is, for example, 12-31 (mm:dd), the result should be:

```
2000-12-31
2001-01-01
2001-01-02
2001-01-03
2001-01-04
2001-31-12
2002-01-01
2002-01-02
2002-01-03
2002-01-04
...
2019-12-31
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
2020-12-31
```

Any tips?

Comment: To confirm, for input `"12-31"` -- `"2000-01-01"` is in `v` and is within five days of `"1999-12-31"`, but shouldn't appear in the result since `"1999-12-31"` isn't in `v`?

Comment: correct @zephryl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function uses `strftime(format = "%m-%d")` to compare dates while ignoring the year, then adds `0` to `n - 1` days to each matching date, then subsets to results that appear in the original dates vector.

```
get_days <- function(dates, mmdd, n = 5) {
  stopifnot(n >= 1)
  out <- dates[strftime(dates, "%m-%d") == mmdd]
  out <- out + rep(0:(n - 1), each = length(out))
  sort(out[out %in% dates])
}

get_days(v, "12-31")
#  [1] "2000-12-31" "2001-01-01" "2001-01-02" "2001-01-03" "2001-01-04" "2001-12-31"
#  [7] "2002-01-01" "2002-01-02" "2002-01-03" "2002-01-04" "2002-12-31" "2003-01-01"
#  ...
# [91] "2018-12-31" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" "2019-12-31"
# [97] "2020-01-01"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `str_detect()` to find the starting value and use the index to find the next 4 rows.

```
library(dplyr)

inital_date = "12-31"

tibble(dates = v)|> 
  mutate(index = stringr::str_detect(v, "12-31")) |> 
  slice(sort(which(index) + rep(0:4, each = sum(index)))) 
      select(-index)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 97 × 1
   dates     
   <date>    
 1 2000-12-31
 2 2001-01-01
 3 2001-01-02
 4 2001-01-03
 5 2001-01-04
 6 2001-12-31
 7 2002-01-01
 8 2002-01-02
 9 2002-01-03
10 2002-01-04
```

Comment: For a more general solution, trying replacing the `slice()` call with `slice(sort(which(index) + rep(0:4, each = sum(index))))`. Then you can easily change `4` to whatever `n` is needed.

Comment: Great, thank you @zephryl! It looked like that they had to be a easier solution, thank you for finding one :)

Answer (score 3):

```r
n <- 5
v <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), 1)
initial_date <- "12-31"
tmp <- rowSums(
  sapply(seq_len(n) - 1, function(z)
    (v-z) %in% v &
      format(v-z, format = "%m-%d") == initial_date)
  ) > 0
v[tmp]
#   [1] "2000-12-31" "2001-01-01" "2001-01-02" "2001-01-03" "2001-01-04" "2001-12-31" "2002-01-01" "2002-01-02" "2002-01-03"
#  [10] "2002-01-04" "2002-12-31" "2003-01-01" "2003-01-02" "2003-01-03" "2003-01-04" "2003-12-31" "2004-01-01" "2004-01-02"
#  [19] "2004-01-03" "2004-01-04" "2004-12-31" "2005-01-01" "2005-01-02" "2005-01-03" "2005-01-04" "2005-12-31" "2006-01-01"
#  [28] "2006-01-02" "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" "2006-12-31" "2007-01-01" "2007-01-02" "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-12-31"
#  [37] "2008-01-01" "2008-01-02" "2008-01-03" "2008-01-04" "2008-12-31" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" "2009-01-04"
#  [46] "2009-12-31" "2010-01-01" "2010-01-02" "2010-01-03" "2010-01-04" "2010-12-31" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03"
#  [55] "2011-01-04" "2011-12-31" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-12-31" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02"
#  [64] "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" "2013-12-31" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-04" "2014-12-31" "2015-01-01"
#  [73] "2015-01-02" "2015-01-03" "2015-01-04" "2015-12-31" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04" "2016-12-31"
#  [82] "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" "2017-12-31" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-02" "2018-01-03" "2018-01-04"
#  [91] "2018-12-31" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" "2019-12-31" "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03"
# [100] "2020-01-04" "2020-12-31"
```

- `(v-z) %in% v` is necessary, since otherwise it'll "match" `1999-12-31` which is not in the original `v`
- `format(v-z, format = "%m-%d")` checks to see if `z` days ago (for all in `v`) matches the `initial_date`
- the return value of `sapply` is a `length(v)`-row, 5-column matrix of logicals, where each row indicates if that row'th `v` should be retained (is within 5 days of `initial_date`). To determine if any on a row are true, we use `rowSums(.) > 0`, which will return a `logical` vector the same length as `v`.

Note: I tried doing this *all at once* using `` outer(v, 0:4, `-`) ``, but matrices in R don't tend to keep the `"Date"` class, and working around that (though it can be done) is a bit onerous. The solution is to produce a matrix that isn't classes as a date, ergo doing the comparison within `sapply`. I tried to reduce the number of "loops" as much as possible, ergo iterating over `0:4` instead of `v`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
initial_date <- "12-31"
n <- 5
tibble(v) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(format(v, '%m-%d') == initial_date) >0) %>% 
  group_by(year = year(v)) %>% 
  slice_head(n = n) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 101 × 2
   v           year
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2000-12-31  2000
 2 2001-01-01  2001
 3 2001-01-02  2001
 4 2001-01-03  2001
 5 2001-01-04  2001
 6 2001-01-05  2001
 7 2002-01-01  2002
 8 2002-01-02  2002
 9 2002-01-03  2002
10 2002-01-04  2002
# … with 91 more rows
```

Comment: For `initial_date <- "12-31"`, your code only returns dates matching `"12-31"`, not `"01-01"`, `"01-02"`, etc, for a total of 20 rows.

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't clear. I just left it in the title that the ```5``` days could be ```n``` days.

Comment: @BryanSouza in the code, i used `n <-5` so you can change the n for the custom days